# Migration from Sencha Touch to EXT JS 6 - Default / Empty Routes for Contoller

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, extjs6

**Problem:**
I am trying to migrate an application from Sencha Touch 2.4.2 to EXT JS 6.0.2 (modern). I am currently struggeling with routes in one of my controllers:

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        routes: {
            '': 'doA',
            ':id': 'doB'
        },
    },
  }
```

What I want is something like the following:

```
http://localhost/    --> doA()
http://localhost/#a  --> doB()
```

`doB()` always works perfect! But somehow the first route doesn't work on EXT JS 6.0.2, but it did work on Sencha Touch 2.4.2. I also tried the following instead of `'' : 'doA'`

1. `' ' : 'doA'` (whitespace)
2. `'*' : 'doA'`
3. `'#' : 'doA'`
4. `'/' : 'doA'`
5. `'.' : 'doA'`

**Question:**
Does anyone know how to get the desired behaviour above?

If I am missing any required information, just let me know in the comments!

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the ExtJS documentation:

> When an application starts, it may be configured to add a default hash
>   if one is not provided. For instance, if the application shows a
>   dashboard when the `#home` hash is used, you may want to add the `#home`
>   hash to the URI if no other hash exists. To enable a default hash, you
>   can use the `default`Token config in the `/app/view/Application.js` file,
>   which can be found within your application:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Application',
    //...
    defaultToken : 'home'
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/router.html#Default_Token

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it and modified my routes to `routes: { 'home': 'doA', ':id': 'doB' }`.That causes a call to `http://localhost/#home` to execute both: doA() and doB()